# Image Button using Twitter Intent with OnClick and OnClientClick

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter

Currently I have an ImageButton labelled, 'Share to Facebook' that uses Facebooks popup and code behind via the onclientclick event.

In the Markup I have the following partial code:

```
<!--Facebook Script-->
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '1637006689963123',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.7'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Twitter Script -->
<script>
    // Performant asynchronous method of loading widgets.js
    window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          t = window.twttr || {};
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function (f) {
            t._e.push(f);
        };

        return t;
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    </script>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgFacebookShare" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Facebook.png" OnClick="imgFacebookShare_Click"/>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTwitterShare" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In the code behind:

```
imgFacebookShare.OnClientClick = "FB.ui({  method: 'share',  href: 'http://example.com',}, function(response){});return true";

Literal TwitterShareURL = new Literal();
TwitterShareURL.Text = "<a href=https://twitter.com/intent/tweet&url=example.com><img border='0' src='Images/Icons/Twitter.png'></a>";
phTwitterShare.Controls.Add(TwitterShareURL);
```

What I need is a Twitter link to tweet the URL, but I am having issues.

While it works fine using an anchor tag, `<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet>Tweet</a>`. I can't figure out how to get it to work via an image button or something with a postback that allows me to use code behind.

Has anybody got something like this to work correctly and willing to give me a hand?

A simple mistake wouldn't surprise me, because these are my first experiments with Twitter.

Comment: You say it works fine doing normal Tweet - can you please show us the code where it works fine, and then the code where it doesn't?

Comment: If I just use a normal link this works. 

<a href=https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=example.com>Tweet</a>

But I can't get it to work at all from an Image Button.

Comment: We need to see your code - the method you use to send it with and without the button. I can't help you if I don't know what you're doing.